# (C++) How to check whether or not an input string is an integer?

Tags: c++

I want this code to check whether the input is an int or not, and it works fine until I enter a float type number. I need a program that won't let through float numbers.

```
bool error;
int x;
string s;
do
{
    cout <<"number: ";
    cin >> x;
    error=cin.fail();
    if(error)
    {
        cout << "error" <<endl;
        cin.clear();
    }
    getline(cin,s);
}while(error);
cout << x;
```

Comment: It be work fine until entered line begins with sequence of digits.

Comment: Read as a string, attempt to [convert to an integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)?

Comment: But I need it to return error whenever a float number is typed in

Comment: @Bako Read in complete whitespace separated chunks and use `std::stoi()` for conversion. Invalid inputs will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in all of the user's input line as a string, [then convert the string to an integer with std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Unfortunately std::stoi will happily stop converting when it hits the end of convertible characters, but it allows you to pass in a pointer to a position to be updated with the character that ended the conversion. If this position is not the end of the string, there was garbage on the line.

```
bool error = true; // assume user input is wrong
while (error)
{    
    if (std::getline(std::cin, s)) // grab the whole line 
    {
        std::size_t end;
        try
        {
            x = std::stoi(s, &end);
            if (end == s.length()) // converted all user input
            {
                error == false; // good data
            }
        }
        catch(std::invalid_argument &) // user input is complete garbage
        {
        }
        catch(std::std::out_of_range &) // converted user input is too big for int.
        {
        }
    }
}
                                  ^
```

I recommend turning the input loop into a function. 1) It's easily reusable should you need to convert an `int` again. 2) It gets rid of some of the logic above because you can `return` when the input is tested and good.

```
int gimmieInt(std::istream& in) // Me eat input stream! Om nom nom nom!
{
    std::string s;
    int x;

    while (true) // consider instead using a maximum number of retries. 
                 // This increases complexity, so consider it *after* you have 
                 // the basic version working 
    {    
        if (std::getline(in, s)) 
        {
            std::size_t end;
            try
            {
                x = std::stoi(s, &end);
                if (end == s.length()) 
                {
                    return x; 
                }
            }
            catch(std::invalid_argument &) // user input is complete garbage
            {
            }
            catch(std::std::out_of_range &) // user input is too big for int.
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::istream& operator(std::istream&, int)` will read a valid integer number up to any non matching character like `'.'`, and no error state is set for the stream up to this point.

You better should read complete (whitespace separeated) chunks as `std::string`, and inspect them if these contain the desired format (e.g. using `std::regex`).

[`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) should also fail with an exception, if you're trying to convert the chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for something like this (C++11):

```
auto s = std::string{};

std::cin >> s;

if( std::all_of(std::begin(s), std::end(s),
                [](char c) -> bool {
                    return c <= '0' && c <= '9';
                }) ) {
    std::cout << "you have entered an integer" << std::endl;
}
```

Somehow I thought, that the standard library contains a predicate that checks if a given char is a digit, but I could not find it now. Such a hypothetic `is_digit()` would allow make the code more readable:

```
if( std::all_of(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::hypothetic::is_digit) ) {
    std::cout << "you have entered an integer" << std::endl;
}
```